# Какая грамматическая основа в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис

У Мешкова отроду не было внутренних тормозов. Грамматическая основа - не было. Правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно. Не было - сказуемое в  безличном предложении.

Answer (score 0):

Да, такое выделение грамматической основы считается верным